# Generating strong password from username

Tags: cryptography, passwords

What I don't want is to generate random password because I may require to refer to the password in future. The requirement is for authentication between 2 machines and only thing I have is usertoken (a unique alphanumeric string identifying a user). The other system however expects username and password. Plus in future I may require to regenerate the same username and password for a given usertoken. Is there a ready Java service that does this? I looked around but there are none. What I could think of is use cryptography to generate 2 new strings from usertoken which allows me to regenerate in future. Thoughts please.

Comment: Can you not simply *store* a password somewhere, instead of trying to reliably *re-generate* the same exact one repeatedly?

Comment: Hash of the token along with proper encoding might be OK (HKDF separately for username and password would be better) depending on who you want to protect this from (threat model). The question remains why you can't store the password and whether there must be some kind of password rules applied.

Comment: Due to business requirements I can't store the password and there are no strict rules needed for the password.

Comment: I feel compelled to note that depending on your threat model this may be insecure. On many systems, it's easy for any user to get a list of all existing usernames, and if the password generation scheme is revealed (e.g. if it's in your app and someone reverse engineers a copy of it), then the password is revealed as well.